# jQuery code is stopping the products from being inserted into the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

When I include the $.post jQuery code, the product info does not get inserted into the database. However, when I remove the $.post jQuery code, the products are successfully inserted into the database.Please help.

**index.html**

```
<html>

    <body>
        <h1>Enter Product Details</h1>
        <form id = "product_form" method = "post" action = "insert.php">
            <input type = "text" id = "n" name = "productname" placeholder = "Product name"></br>
            <input type = "text" id = "b" name = "brandname" placeholder = "Brand name"></br>
            <input type = "number" id = "q" name = "quantity" placeholder = "Quantity"></br>
            <button id = "save_button">Save information</button>
        </form>

        <p id = "result"></p>

        <button id = "btn">Test Button</button>


        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/script.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['productname']; //'productname' is from html input
    $brand = $_POST['brandname']; //'brandname' is from html input
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity']; //'quantity' is from html input

    $con = new mysqli ('localhost', 'root', '', 'tutorial');

    if ($con -> connect_error) {
        echo 'database connect error';
    }

    //Prepare statement to insert into database
    $stmt = $con -> prepare ("INSERT into products(name, brand, quantity) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    // Bind the variables to the values
    $stmt -> bind_param ("ssi", $name, $brand, $quantity);
    //Execute
    if($stmt -> execute()){
        echo "success";
    }
    else {
        echo "failure";
    }

?>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#btn').click(function(){
        alert();
    });

    //The problem code!!!!
    $('#product_form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();     
        $.post(
            'insert.php',
            {
                productname:$("#n").val(),
                brandname:$("#b").val(),
                value:$("#q").val(),
            },
            function(result){
                if(result == "success"){
                    $("#result").html("Values inserted successfully!");
                }
                else{
                    $("#result").html("Error!");
                }
            }
        );
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I think you need a `type="submit"` on your button to make that code work  `<button type="submit" id = "save_button">Save information</button>` Otherwise the button wont generate a submit event

Comment: @RiggsFolly I put the id = "save_button". However, it is still not inserting.

Comment: Right, but a button does not generate the submit event, without a `type="submit"` and youare trying to catch a submit event

Comment: do you see the ajax request in devtools and do you get the "Error!" message?

Comment: @Riggs I apologize, I meant to say I put the type = "submit". However, still not inserting into the database.

Comment: @James Yes, 'Error!' does appear. I don't know how to see the ajax request.

Comment: the var `result` contains the server response.  so display it and see what it says, it's definitely not == `success` - you could also see the response in devtools.  in chrome hit f12, network tab, then submit your form you should see a new request appear click on it and look for the server response

Comment: ps @RiggsFolly The default behavior of a button on a form is to submit the form, [check](https://jsfiddle.net/msj6kwjL/1/) Having said that when I code these I use `<input type='submit'>` partially out of habit and partially to make the code clearer.

Comment: @James Thank you for teaching me server response. I'll definitely use it in the future. It gives the following error on preview: "Notice: Undefined index: quantity in...line 7" I don't understand though, the quantity in the html is exactly the same as in the php code?

Comment: Devtools really is an invaluable debugger for this type of thing.  Enjoy!

Comment: @James Thats an `<input>` Button. Its not the case for a `<button>` type button

Comment: @RiggsFolly [Check the fiddle again](https://jsfiddle.net/msj6kwjL/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second parameter to $.post you set the data to send to the server, you have

```
{
  productname:$("#n").val(),
  brandname:$("#b").val(),
  value:$("#q").val()
}
```

So you need to change `value:` to `quantity:`, in order to have the ajax submission match what the traditional form submit would produce.